# What quantity can be used to robustly estimate a specific (dimensionless) variation (variance) of a sequence?

Tags: estimation, robust

What quantity can be used to robustly estimate a specific variation of a sequence?

By "specific" I mean "dimensionless, per-unit" etc, that is, independent on units of measurement and independent on mean value.

I started from the normalized deviation, which is the ratio of sequence deviation to sequence range, but this quantity seems to be non-robust. There is a robust estimate of scale to use instead of the sequence range, an inter-quartile range. But I don't know what to use as a robust estimate of sequence deviation. I'm also not sure that ratio of robust estimates is a robust estimate itself.

Or maybe I'm inventing a wheel and there's a common quantity used to robustly estimate a specific variation of a sequence?

EDIT: I'd like to add the background of the problem. I have a quantity that multiplicatively depends on two factors plus some noise factor. I have a lot of experimental data - values of a function at certain factor locations. I have derived two sequences representing the estimates of each factor influence on a target function. At the moment, I compensate for those factors by using the inverse of the influence estimates, damped by the scales of 0.5. In case of equal factor influences this works fine, but when one factor behaves smooth and other factor behaves rough, the 0.5/0.5 damping works poorly. I need to use damping proportional to the roughness of the factor, so that the calm factor is almost ignored, while the rough factor is compensated at almost 100% strength. So I need some quantity to estimate the roughness of a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a full answer to your question, but median absolute deviation (MAD) is often used as a robust alternative to standard deviation (SD). MAD isn't dimension free, but you could divide MAD by the median.

Comment: Yes, that would probably worth trying. I just thought about it. But, shouldn't we divide MAD by median of absolute values instead?

Comment: Interesting question @mbaitoff; I am not sure.  Probably, because otherwise adding a constant to all observations would potentially change the value.

Comment: Looks like we cannot satisfy shift-independency and scale-independency at the same time, and I have to choose one of the properties.

Comment: I added the background of the problem if you're interested. Probably this will help getting a clue about what I search for.

Comment: Would you divide the MAD by the absolute value of the median or by the median of the absolute values?

Comment: I wouldn't divide it by anything

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but it sounds somewhat self-contradictory. Dimensionless or independent of units means to me that $f(a \cdot x_1, \dotsc, a \cdot x_n) = f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ for (most?) nonzero $a$, but a measure of variation would for me mean that you want $f(a \cdot x_1, \dotsc, a \cdot x_n) = a \cdot f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$. And you can't have both.

It sounds like you would like to know something like, what fraction of your measurements is far away from the mean, expressed in standard deviations. This sounds more like [kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) than variation. So are we looking for a robust version of kurtosis?

---

Edited to add: if we are indeed looking for that, you could check to see if the [L-kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-moment) satisfies your needs.

Comment: Well, I meant 'variation' without implying affine properties relative to it's arguments, so I didn't expect the second equation to hold.